# failed to parse field [review_start_datetime] of type [date] in document with id 'DEMO_54ddab6'

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

**Index Mapping**

```
"review_start_datetime" : {
   "type" : "date"
},
"review_start_time" : {
   "type" : "date"
}
```

**Class**

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import Document, Date

class DocumentX(Document):
    review_start_datetime = Date(format='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss',
                            default_timezone="UTC")
```

**Creating Data**

```
doc = DocumentX.get('DEMO_54ddab6')
doc.review_start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
doc.review_start_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
doc.save()
```

While executing save method it gives below error only for **review_start_datetime** field not for **review_start_time**.

> elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400,
> 'mapper_parsing_exception', "failed to parse field
> [review_start_datetime] of type [date] in document with id
> 'DEMO_54ddab6'")

Comment: Are you sure 'format' is not defined for the review_start_datetime ?

Comment: @SahilGupta yes. Mapping the same as to mention above.

Comment: you are dumping a `datetime` object into that field and ES is expecting something more like string. Use `obj.strftime('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')` to parse the object

Answer (score 3):

By Adding DateTime format in index mapping it will resolve.

```
"review_start_datetime" : {
    "type" : "date",
    "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error in various tools, e.g., Apache NiFi, and Logstash. The problem in my case is that I want to put MongoDB documents in the Elasticsearch index, where these documents already include the `_id` field, and when I want to make that Elasticsearch database, the new field `_id` will be made that can not exist with the earlier one. So, this results in the error. The solution may be to remove/change `_id` field in the documents before putting them into Elastic.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30069096)